# Use fgetcsv for tab delimited file

Tags: php

Is it possible to use `fgetcsv` in PHP to open a tab-delimited file?

Answer (score 48):

```
$csvData = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, "\t");
```

Where `$fileHandle` is a valid file handle. The 0 is just to tell the function not to limit seeking through lines (however you can change this to suit, the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) do say not imposing a limit decreases performance).

Comment: is the tab delimiter different for macs?

Comment: @Brian I've had a quick Google, and I don't think so. Usually that's just line endings and line feeds.

Comment: I get this error when trying to use "\t" for delimiter? fgetcsv(): delimiter must be a single character

Comment: @PrimozRome Are you sure you're using double quotes for it?

Comment: @alex ah I see, thanks for the note! It's working with double quotes

Answer (score 29):

Make sure to use double quotes around the "\t", single quotes will not work.

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop statement is missing two parentheses. It should look more like `while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t")) !== false)`, otherwise `$line` will be returned as a boolean.

Comment: This is a curious example, because *yes* it works 100% of the time as written, but might not work as it is *interpreted*

Comment: @Paul Richards Thanks helps a lot, I was using single quote

Answer (score 10):

yes, you can specify tab "\t" in its parameters. see the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE)
```