# how to seperate csv contents by tab

Tags: php

I am gong to convert CSV files to PHP array. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> ".$num." fields in line". $row.": <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is it really a tab character? Try `"\t"`.

Comment: Use `"\t"` as the tab escape sequence

Comment: Try `\t` if it's an actual tab character.

Comment: Seems to be somewhat of a consensus on the issue so far ;).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use fgetcsv for tab delimited file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582021/use-fgetcsv-for-tab-delimited-file)

Comment: Your last edit fundamentally changed the question. Before it was a question about how to represent the tab character in `fgetcsv`. Now it appears to be more of an encoding problem. You shouldn't make edits to your questions that invalidate existing answers, (even if those answers weren't really necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

The correct PHP escape sequence for a tab is `"\t"`.

Try `$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")`

And check out the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) on escape sequences