# join array elements in foreach

Tags: php, forms

I have a form where I'm trying to extract elements from tab separated data.
(Users pastes lines from excel spreadsheet).
I want to extract elements from each line and create a new comma delimited variable for use later on.

It's only a small section of spreadsheet, not the entire file. The fields in excel may not be in same location. fgetcsv is not an option.

My data from excel:

```
S2HA-E-701  10G 4/0/11  S2WS-SPE-201    10G 0/39    J S2HA S2WS N101 
S2HA-E-701  10G 4/0/12  S2WS-SPE-201    10G 0/38    J S2HA S2WS N102
```

From my $_post:

```
$link_dataw=$_POST["link_dataw"];
var_dump($link_dataw);
```

Output of var_dump:

```
string(121) "S2DO-E-701 Te0/0/1/1 S2WE-SPE-201 Te 0/39 J S2DO S2WE N101 S2DO-E-701 Te0/0/1/2 S2WE-SPE-201 Te 0/38 J S2DO S2WE N102 " 

{
$link_arrayw = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', preg_replace('/\t/',',',$link_dataw)); //split on new line convert tabs to ,

var_dump ($link_arrayw);
```

```
//result
array(2) { 
[0]=> string(60) "S2DO-E-701,Te0/0/1/1,S2WE-SPE-201,Te 0/39,J S2DO S2WE N101 " [1]=> string(60) "S2DO-E-701,Te0/0/1/2,S2WE-SPE-201,Te 0/38,J S2DO S2WE N102 " }
```

```
foreach ($link_arrayw as $v){ 

$link_1w = preg_split("/,/",trim($v));  // split on comma, cleanup any spaces
$link_1w = array_map('trim', $link_1w); // cleanup any spaces

$arr1 =($link_1w[0]);
$arr2 =($link_1w[1]);
$arr3 =($link_1w[2]);
$arr4 =($link_1w[3]);
$arr5 =($link_1w[4]);

$new_array5 = $arr5.','.$arr5;
print_r ($new_array5);  //What I'm trying to achieve (doesn't work)
}

$new_array5 = $arr5.','.$arr5 //What I'm trying to achieve (doesn't work either)
```

Desired result:

```
$new_array5 = "J S2HA S2WS N101,J S2HA S2WS N102";
```

For use further on.

Comment: Why not process the csv file with `\t` as the value delimiter?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582041/2943403  I've gotta say, this needs to rewritten with better techniques.  `preg_split('/,/')` is an inefficient way of explode()ing a string on commas.  If you are going to immediately call trim after exploding, then why not preg_split() with `/\s*,\s*`?  Ultimately, don't do this.  Just use the right function from the beginning. `while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t")) !== false) {`

Comment: Thanks for feedback
It's only a small section of spreadsheet, not the entire file. The fields in excel may not be in same location. fgetcsv is not an option.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php  A good clear question would show `var_export($link_dataw)` and the exact desired output.